# How to make Google ignore where I am in the world?

Tags: google-search, localization

Whenever I travel around the world Google always assumes I want to use the region I am in as the search engine.

I just want to always search Google.co.uk wherever I am in the world. I don't want to see foreign results and foreign languages and foreign countries results.

How do I default Google and Chrome to this?

Answer (score 2):

When you navigate to the website go to `https://www.google.co.uk/ncr`, the "ncr" stands for "No Country Redirect". It will keep you on whichever version you initially visited.

Comment: Can I change this is google Chrome's settings or do I have to type this manually?

Comment: @TheLearner - Which settings are you specifically talking about?

Comment: Google Chrome for macOS and iOS

Comment: I didn't ask what operating systems, I asked, which chrome settings are you talking about specifically?

Comment: @Ramhound, I think you missunderstood the question.  They were asking IF there were any chrome settings that could be used to change this.  Or they are asking US if there are any settings that can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Set the **Google Chrome** *Home Page* and the *Startup Pages* to have a URL value of https://www.google.com/?gl=us&gws_rd=ssl, and then just use the **Home Page** button to open this specific URL rather than typing in Google.com in your web browser address bar.

You could additionally save this same URL as a shortcut, favorite and so on, and just click it rather than typing Google.com into the web browser address bar.

Please note that the ending URL parts such as **`?gl=us`** may vary depending on your originating country so determine your county code value for this and plug it in accordingly.

---

Click **Settings**

[image]

In the **On Startup** section select the **Set Pages** option from the *Open specific page or set of pages*. Set the URL value accordingly here in the **Startup Pages** window for your country.

In the **Appearance** section check the **Show Home Button**, press the **Change** option, and then in the **Home Page** window, set your URL value accordingly.

[image]
[image]

[image]

<sub>[source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/ovzMVjObXDw)</sub>